# setting a string with NULL

Tags: c, string, null

I've got some metadata (mplayer's output) in allocated RAM, and I'm trying to set some pointers to the strings contained therein. So far I've declared these pointers as `char *`, although I'm not certain if they shouldn't perhaps be `void *`, but in any case the code then scans forwards and substitutes the following linefeed character with a zero to terminate the string conventionally so the rest of the program can use it.

My question really is: When a keyword is not found, the relevant pointer will have not been correctly assigned, and therefore could be pointing anywhere. I've tried to solve this by initially setting it to NULL with `meta[which]=NULL;`. This is further complicated because there are three of them. I'm not certain whether meta[2] is the first character of the second string, or the second character in the zero'th string. Anyway, it's not working as it is.

Here is the code:

```
if (malc)   // Locate the strings of metadata information in the memory.
{
int which;
char keyword[3][23]={"ANS_metadata/artist=","ANS_metadata/title=","ANS_path="};
for (which=0;which<3;which++)
    {
    int memc,strc;
    meta[which]=NULL;
    for (memc=0,strc=0;memc<MPLAYER_MEM;memc++)
        {
        if (keyword[which][strc])   // Not Zero while string match is incomplete.
            {
            if (*(malc+memc)==keyword[which][strc])
                strc++;
            else
                strc=0;
            }
        else      // If we reach the end of the keyword, then we've found it.
            {
            meta[which]=malc+memc;          // Find the end of the line and
            while (*(malc+memc)!=LINEFEED)  // terminate it more conventionally.
                memc++;                     // Now meta[] points to our strings.
            *(malc+memc)=0;                 
            break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone got any ideas? Thankyou.

EDIT: Sorry, guys, I forgot these:

```
char *malc=malloc(MPLAYER_MEM);
char *meta[2];
```

EDIT: Added `break`.

Comment: Show declaration of _meta_

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do, but I have a gut feeling that you are confusing a pointer with a character, and `NULL` with the character `\0` (and many other things as well).

Comment: What I'm trying to do is assign pointers to the strings contained within the RAM I've malloc'd. But the strings might not be there, in which case the pointers need NULLing so they're testable for that condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 keywords, so meta needs to be of length 3 as well:

```
char *meta[3];
```

Using NULL to signify a missing keyword is the right way to do it.

Comment: Good grief, I can't believe I missed that! Thanks for confirmation on the NULL thing as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand but if you have these metadata:

`ANS_metadata/title=test2\nANS_metadata/artist=this is a test\nunused_metadata=unused\nANS_path=test4`

and want this result:

- 0: `ANS_metadata/artist=this is a test`
- 1: `ANS_metadata/title=test2`
- 2: `ANS_path=test4`

You could do like this:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define LINEFEED '\n'

#define NB_META (3)
int main(char** argv,int argc) {
    char* meta[NB_META]={NULL};
    char malc[]="ANS_metadata/title=test2\nANS_metadata/artist=this is a test\nunused_metadata=unused\nANS_path=test4";

    if (malc) {  // Locate the strings of metadata information in the memory.
        char* keyword[NB_META]={"ANS_metadata/artist=","ANS_metadata/title=","ANS_path="};

        int MPLAYER_MEM = strlen(malc);

        for(int which=NB_META;which;--which) {

            int len = strlen(keyword[which]);

            char* addr = malc;

            char* endAddr= addr+MPLAYER_MEM-len;

            while( (addr <= endAddr)
                  && ( 0 != strncmp( keyword[which],addr,len) )  )
            {addr++;}

            if(addr <= endAddr) {
                meta[which]=addr;          // Find the end of the line and
                while (*addr!=LINEFEED) {  // terminate it more conventionally.
                    addr++;                     // Now meta[] points to our strings.
                } 
                *addr=0;
                printf("%d : %s\n",which,meta[which]);                 
    }   }   }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, you've understood what I was trying to achieve. However, the fault wasn't finding the strings, which is what you seem to have offered a solution for. My code identifies the strings by upon reaching the NULL string terminator for the keywords i'm searching for, the `if` statement fails, and that's where the pointer is set. Your method (not compiled it) looks to me like it calls `strlen` twice with each iteration. The malloc is 250 bytes, loops 3 times. That's 1500 strlen's!! I do take your point about the `NB_META`, which would have saved me the stupid error I made. Thanks for that.

Comment: strlen can be factorized if the compiler don't do it for yourself. Sorry not to have understood the question. About NB_META, coding standards often forbid the use of constants directly in the code. Also, pay attention that I think the metadata must be ordered for your code to work (I don't know if something you wanted).

Comment: I'm intrigued by this about strlen being factorized by the compiler automatically. Is gcc really that clever? How would you find out if it's doing this or not? Is there a way?

Comment: I would probably use `strstr` to locate the keys (followed by `strchr` to find `\n`), but if you want to handle the possibility of the keys appearing in the data then my code wouldn't be much shorter than Lees original code.

Comment: Yes you are right gcc is not able to optimize this. The only way I know how to check this is to use a debugger and have a look to the generated assembly code. For instance I used ddd (the name of the debugger) and strlen is duplicated even if I use the maximum optimization level. I updated my response therefore accordingly.